# Campagnolo rear mech screw type

Tags: derailleur-rear, replacement, campagnolo, adjustment-screw

My limit screws' heads have gone rusty, I want to replace them for looks and to make sure they are easy to adjust on a ride. I would love hex rather than Philips heads!

Does anyone know the type of screw these are e.g. M4? Are they the same as SRAM and Shimano? I just want to put the right thing in and not put my bike out of action.

Comment: Take one of the screws to a hardware store and match it up.

Comment: Better still a bike store than a hardware store. They certainly have stock of small bits and pieces with the correct type of screws.

Comment: By all means replace the rusty screws before they get any worse. However you don't need to adjust the limit screws once the bike is built, unless it's taken some damage in a crash and is all out of whack, so they don't need to be 'easy to adjust on a ride'.